# Searching word from file_1 in file_2

Tags: python

I need to have following output:
Function should return True, if any word from file 1 is found in file 2. otherwise function should return False:
In file_1 each line should consists of one word.

```
def search_in_file(filepath_1, filepath_2):
    wordlist_1=[]
    f = open(filepath_1, "r")
    for line in f:
        wordlist_1.append(line)
    print wordlist_1

    wordlist_2=[]
    f = open(filepath_2, "r")
    for line in f:
        wordlist_2.append(line)
    print wordlist_2

    for i in wordlist_1:
        if i in wordlist_2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I still got False, but some of words from file_1 are visible in file_2. Could someone help?

Comment: A function can only `return` once, so you only get the result for comparing the first word in each list.

Comment: Do both files contain one word per line, or could file 2 contain multiple words? If so, how should we determine where a word starts/ends? In other words, how are the words separated from each other?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`set`s](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) for this:

```
def search_in_file(filepath_1, filepath_2):
    wordlist_1=set(open(filepath_1))
    wordlist_2=set(open(filepath_2))
    return wordlist_1 & wordlist_2 != set() # Check if set intersection is not empty
    # Of course, you could simply return wordlist_1 & wordlist_2,
    # that way you'd know the actual set of all matching words.
```

Note that line endings are preserved when reading a file line by line. Therefore, if the last line of the file doesn't end in a newline, matches may be missed.

Comment: This is by-line check, not by word.

Comment: @volcano: Hm, he did write that there is one word per line, but he only mentioned this for file 1. We need clarification.

Comment: Tim Pietzcker, then you definitely have to _strip()_ words from the first. Just a thought - may _any_  - applied on words from file1 vs set of file2 - be more efficient than _set_ in this case - after all, building set on large quantity of string may be time-consuming?

Answer (score 0):

```
def search_in_file(filepath_1, filepath_2):
 wordlist_1=[]
 f = open(filepath_1, "r")
 for line in f:
     wordlist_1.append(line)
 print wordlist_1

 wordlist_2=[]
 f = open(filepath_2, "r")
 for line in f:
     wordlist_2.append(line)
 print wordlist_2

 for i in wordlist_1:
     if i in wordlist_2:
         return True
 return False
```

Comment: This may be inefficient, but it does the job, so I don't see why this was downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

1. use `with` statement, `open`, and `read` method to get file content.
2. Use `split()` method to create `list` of file content.
3. Use `set` method to get common values from two list

input:

File: "/home/vivek/Desktop/input1.txt"

```
file first 
I have some word from file second
Good
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

File: "/home/vivek/Desktop/input2.txt"

```
file second 
I have some word from file first
Good 
5 6 7 8  9 0
```

Code:

```
def searchInFile(filepath_1, filepath_2):
    with open(filepath_1, "r") as fp:
        wordlist_1 = fp.read().split()

    with open(filepath_2, "r") as fp:
        wordlist_2 = fp.read().split()

    common = set(wordlist_1).intersection(set(wordlist_2))

    return list(common)


filepath_1 = "/home/vivek/Desktop/input1.txt"
filepath_2 = "/home/vivek/Desktop/input2.txt"

result = searchInFile(filepath_1, filepath_2)
print "result:", result
if result:
    print "Words are common in two files."
else:
    print "No Word is common in two files."
```

Output:

```
infogrid@infogrid-172:~$ python  workspace/vtestproject/study/test.py
result: ['Good', 'word', 'file', 'I', 'have', 'some', 'second', '5', '7', '6', 'from', 'first']
Words are common in two files.
```

Comment: What happens if text contains `.,\?` etc?

Comment: Good point. The content is split on `\n`, `\t`, `\r`, ` `. So if there are `.`, `,` and etc then thy are words. I think we need to remove such characters from the file content before compare.